# Setting opacity of an element breaks scrolling of parent in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I am having a bug I don't understand at all and that I can't find an solution for on the web.

My setup is pretty simple: I'm having a container with various children. The container (marked red in the screenshot) has a fixed height and overflow-y auto. Scrolling works just as expected.

[image: scrlling works]

```
.card-details-container {
    height: 500px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

But when I change the opacity of one of the contained children, it is suddenly broken:

[image: scrolling is broken]

```
.barchart .barchart-bars div    {
    opacity: .5;
}
```

I am only experiencing this bug in Chrome (41.0.2272.118). I have no idea why this would be happening. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
/* Theoretically for IE 8 & 9 (more valid) */   
/* ...but not required as filter works too */
/* should come BEFORE filter */
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";

/* This works in IE 8 & 9 too */
/* ... but also 5, 6, 7 */
filter: alpha(opacity=50);

/* Older than Firefox 0.9 */
-moz-opacity:0.5;

/* Safari 1.x (pre WebKit!) */
-khtml-opacity: 0.5;

/* Modern!
/* Firefox 0.9+, Safari 2?, Chrome any?
/* Opera 9+, IE 9+ */
opacity: 0.5;
```

Also, check the borders.

Comment: This seems pretty random.

Comment: No, this didn't help :( I'm not quite sure what you mean by "Check the borders", but the position of the element is fine if looked at in the inspector, if I give the element a border it's drawn at the right place (I'm using box-sizing: border-box;). The only thing that's off is the scrollbar (opacity is generally working, it just breaks scrolling)

Comment: try width: 100% or width: auto for the container

Comment: That didn't change anything either. I can't wrap my head around why changing the opacity would result in such a weird layout change (well, not the visible layout but apparently what the browser thinks the layout is)